# Mongo DB update nested object using Mongo C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm not familiar with mongodb a lot and I like the document oriented databases. My application have these business entity classes:

```
public class ItemCategory
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Double)]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Context class

```
public class MongoDbContext
{
    private MongoDatabase database;

    public MongoDatabase Database
    {
        get { return database; }
        set { database = value; }
    }

    public MongoDbContext()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(Settings.Default.constr);
        var server = client.GetServer();
        Database= server.GetDatabase(Settings.Default.db);            
    }

    public MongoCollection<ItemCategory> ItemCategories 
    { 
        get
        {
            return Database.GetCollection<ItemCategory>("itemcategories"); 
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to update a specific "Item" entity by Id which is nested inside "ItemCategory" entity, how should I do it.

Comment: what do you want to update?

Answer (score -1):

> At first you should find you target document via `Query` class, then you have to use `Update` class to update your document

In my sample I updated the `CategoryName` property of a document from `"old name"` to `"new category name"`

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<ItemCategory>("itemcategories");

var query = Query.And(Query<ItemCategory>.EQ(c => c.Id, "id"), Query<ItemCategory>.EQ(c => c.CategoryName, "old name"));
var update = Update<ItemCategory>.Set(c => c.CategoryName, "new category name");

collection.Update(query, update);
```

Comment: I want to update a specific "Item" entity by Id which is nested inside "ItemCategory" entity, how should I do it

Comment: put a sample document, and your desired result in your question